# unable to launch android emulator due to error in installing intelhaxm

Tags: android, android-emulator, hyper-v

I m getting the following error when i start my emulator
Starting emulator for AVD 'MyAVD'
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

I downloaded the intelhaxm and m trying to run the application file so it shows "VT not supported"
then i went to cmd and tried dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
but i got the following error
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.1.7600.16385

Image Version: 6.1.7601.18489

Error: 0x800f080c

Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown.
A Windows feature name was not recognized.
Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and tr
y the command again.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log

i tried disabling hyperv from control panel--programs and features but it is not listed there

please help

Comment: I get the same error. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it.  Make sure you have enabled hardware virtualization in your BIOS, should be under CPU Configuration.  Once I had that enabled, the haxm installer ran without any problems.  As for Microsoft-Hyper-V, it doesn't seem to be a feature (leastwise it's not listed) so I don't know what's up with that.